# Reset filter parameters no working using SApUI5

Tags: sapui5

After applying that filter, it adds to the request

**&$filter=contains(Status, eq 'active')&$skip=0&$top=100**

What I need is to be able to remove that filter
I tried to remove it with the Filter model

```
var oFilterModel = this.getView ().getModel("filters");
oFilterModel.setProperty ("/", {});
```

which if you reset the other filters of the type

```
aFilters.push (new Filter ("Name", FilterOperator.Contains, sName));
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that you try to manipulate the model. The filtering happens in the binding of the model. Therefore, you need to change the binding of the aggregation.

As shown [here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.30.8/docs/guide/5295470d7eee46c1898ee46c1b9ad763.html):

```
var oList = this.getView().byId("invoiceList");
var oBinding = oList.getBinding("items");
oBinding.filter([]);
```